# How to handle field-level permissions and return only allowed fields from serializer?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, permissions

Ok, first off, I've read the docs on DRF permissions, all hits I've found here in SO, and in Google-land.

I'm trying to return only the fields a user can view based on field-level permissions.  I've seen examples of how to dynamically modify the "fields" attribute of a serializer in the `__init__` method, and that seems like the best place to do what I need to do.  But during the process of getting the current user's permissions, I need to raise an exception if the user is invalid or has no permissions at all.

The problem is that `__init__` seems to be executing during a request even if the request is not the endpoint that `__init__` code is for.

Here's my serializer:

```py
class ClientSerializer(AddressPhoneSerializerMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="clients:client-detail")
    contacts = ClientContactsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    projects = ClientProjectsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    project_users = ClientProjectUsersSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = (
            'url',
            'id',
            'name',
            'slug',
            'status',
            'address',
            'country',
            'phone_number',
            'mobile_number',
            'fax_number',
            'created',
            'updated',
            'deleted',
            'contacts',
            'projects',
            'project_users',
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClientSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.check_permissions()

    def check_permissions(self):
        permissions = None

        request = self.context.get("request")
        if request and hasattr(request, "user"):
            user = request.user
            permissions = UserPermissionsList(user.id)

        if not permissions or permissions is None:
            raise PermissionDenied('You do not have permission to view clients.')

        for field_name in self.fields:
            if not user.has_perm('clients.view_%s' % field_name):
                self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

When I load just the root of the site: `example.com/` (not the clients list: `example.com/clients/`), I get the exception ("You do not have permission to view clients.").  So it seems that code is running on *any* page load, not just when accessing clients.  Is that because URLSconf imports the Client model and the Client model imports the serializer?  If so, why is the serializer being instantiated when clients are not being accessed?

I know that object-level permissions are usually relegated to view(s), but if I put field-level permissions there, I don't see how I can remove certain fields from the serialized JSON that is returned.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe look around https://github.com/tiliv/django-field-permissions

Comment: Thanks for that link @Antwane.  Looks like it has potential, though it doesn't seem to have had any activity in over three years.